# Can't delete action when setting event delegate for list items

Tags: jquery

In line 79, setting the event delegate for `.details ul` can be deleted normally, but changing it to `.details u li` why can't delete operation? Can't the p tag bubble up to the .details ul li? I don't know why it is?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    if ($('.message').val()) {
      var li = $('<li></li>');
      li.html($('.message').val() + '<p>删除</p>');
      $('ul').prepend(li);
      li.slideDown();
      $('.message').val("");
    }
  })
  $('.details ul').on('click', 'p', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  })

})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.main {
  margin: 50px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 560px;
}

.message {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 437px;
  height: 156px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}

.info {
  margin-top: 140px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 140px;
}

.info,
.message,
.btn {
  float: left;
}

.details {
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 170px;
  width: 437px;
}

.details ul li {
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

.details ul li p {
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="../../jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<div class="main">
  <div class="info">微博发布</div>
  <textarea name="" class="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="发布" class="btn">
  <div class="details">
    <ul>
      <li>hello
        <p>delete</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSsRC.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  I've converted your code to a snippet and added a relevant jquery link.  Please review the snippet.   It *appears* to work correctly - perhaps you could describe how / add steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It could be that you've provided the *working* code instead of the *not-working* code - you state when you change to `details u li` - perhaps it's a simple typo as that should be `details ul li` - please update the snippet to **demonstrate the issue**